# setInterval is 'pausing' the navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm running a javascript (basic) setInterval function, this runs every 5 seconds, go to the mlab api, get some data, and refresh the DOM, but, the problem here is that if I'm typing at the same moment that the setInterval get executed, the screen is 'paused' for a moment and I get the control once the setInterval function finished.

here is some code

```
stopInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
              url: encodeURI
              async: false,
              contentType: "application/json",
              success: function(response) {
                    $('#farDiv').append(response);
              });
}, 5000);
```

There is a way to run setInterval and not 'pause' (I can't find a good definition for this behavior) the entire DOM?

(I assigned the function to a variable in order to use clearInterval(stopInterval)) when need)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? or the complete code you have tried till now.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want `async: true` so that the ajax call can run in the background and not block the main UI.